# MVC, how to avoid the Routing class from coupling with the Model?

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, url-routing

I'm working on a Routing class in a MVC website. Some routes may contain a username :

```
http://www.domain.com/John-Smith/
```

Others a tag :

```
http://www.domain.com/Fun-Stuff/
```

The Routing class will need to detect if there is a username or a tag present in the URL. This means that the Routing class will need access to the User Model and the Tag Model to compare url segments against the database.

For now only my controllers are in contact with the model, and it doesn't feel right to couple the Routing class with the model. Is there a way, or any architectural solution to avoid this ?

Comment: Or maybe it's just fine for a Routing class to access the model ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've missed the point of routing. It can do almost anything you want. **You** tell it where to map to. Take the example of the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{something}",
    new { controller="MyDefault", action="Something", something=""});
```

So with the url `http://mydomain.com/miles-davis1234/` it would match to the controller and action specified in the routing. On the following action you could then use the value of the `{something}` token:

```
public ActionResult Something(string something)
{
    // something = miles-davis1234
    var x = this._myService.WorkOutWhatSomethingIs(something);

    // now do something with x
}
```

So in answer to your query about "detecting whether it's a username or a tag" you could do something like the above. Although I wouldn't recommend it. I would do the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Users",
    "User/{username}",
    new { controller="User", action="Detail", username="" });

routes.MapRoute(
    "Tags",
    "Tag/{tag}",
    new { controller="Tag", action="Search", tag="" });
```

Because if you're trying to do tags and usernames using the same route / token, what happens, for example, when somebody's username is the same as a tag? You couldn't tell the difference. And anyway, the point of the MVC pattern is "RESTful" urls. The should *represent* the controller (model), action and any other metadata. In your instance you could (and probably should) even use the basic `{controller}/{action}/{data}` pattern for your routing. It would do exactly what you need from a data point of view.